# R: Plot ecdf of one column on an axis of another column with ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, ecdf

I'm sure this can be done by separately collecting all the data and then just using ggplot for the plotting, but I'd really prefer a simpler solution implementing ggplot, particulalry stat_ecdf() because of easier access to grouping variables, facets, etc.

My dataframe contains, amongst others, two columns of corresponding data x and y. I'd like to plot the ecdf of y on an axis of the corresponding x values. In other words, I'd like to plot what cumulative portion of the y variable is reached at its corresponding x value. While x and y are correlated (both descending), they are not analytically connected, so I cannot simply scale values of y to x. My attempts to do this with separate calculations of the ecdf functions of each subset have gotten extremely messy and complicated, while the stat_ecdf function seems to be very close to getting me what I need.

If I set the x variable in the ggplot aes to x and then set the variable within stat_ecdf to y, I am able to get the ecdf of y with axis labels of x; however, the actual values on the axis correspond to x. I'm plotting  This is done with something like:

`ggplot(df, aes(x, color=group_var)) + stat_ecdf(aes(y))`

EDIT:
To visualize this:
[This sample plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WklJt.png)
shows the ecdf of x for multiple groups. Each x value has a corresponding y value in a sorted dataframe ([approximate relationship, ignore the decreasing regions at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsd9F.png). I would like to have a similar plot where the horizontal axis is in the corresponding y values. Basically, I need to map the horizontal axis of the first ecdf plot from x->y as simply as possible. I could do this manually by adding ecdf values as a column in the dataframe, but I am looking to do it within ggplot for simplicity, if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve? ecdf is by definition calculated from a single variable. If you can describe the desired transformation clearly, it will be probably easy to deal with the 'separate calculations' here.. are you trying to plot `x` versus the `quantile` of `y`?

Comment: I'm not trying to plot against the quantile. I want to plot the ecdf of one variable on an axis of corresponding values of another. For example, if I have  columns of corresponding height and weight, with both guaranteed to be descending, I would like to plot the ecdf of weight on an axis of height (to see what portion of the total weight is made up by people of a certain height or below.

Comment: Edited to give example

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. This said: One issue with your code is that you should do `stat_ecdf(aes(y = y))` to get the ecdf of y versus x.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to bend `stat_ecdf` to do something it was not designed for, it's better to be explicit about your intention in the code.

It's quite straightforward. The most weird piece of code: `ecdf(y)(y)` menas 'calculate the empirical CDF for `y`, and then evaluate it for the actual values of `y` in my data. The `cummax` deals with the decreasing `y`, to get ever increasing eCDF along `x`.

```
d_sample %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  arrange(group, x) %>%
  mutate(
    fraction = ecdf(y)(y),
    maxf = pmax(fraction, cummax(fraction))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, maxf)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image: ecdf of the sample data]

I'm still not really sure if that's what you need.

### Sample data

To be honest it took me most of the time to 'fake' your dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = seq_len(300) + 100) %>%
  mutate(
    one = - 1e-3 * (x * x) + 50 + 0.7 * x,
    two = - 1e-3 * (x * x) + 55 + 0.68 * x,
    three = - 1e-3 * (x * x) + 110 + 0.5 * x,
    four = - 1e-3 * (x * x) + 10 + 0.8 * x) %>%
  pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "group", values_to = "y") %>%
  filter(
    group == "one"
    | group == "two"
    | (group == "three" & x < 200)
    | (group == "four" & x > 250)) ->
  d_sample

d_sample %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, colour = group)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: sample data scatter plot]